# Solve Differential Equation [Trig Functions]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x\cos(y) +\sin(2y))}$.

I'm not really sure how to even start solving this differential equation. I tried seeing if it was seperable, it wasn't, and then I tried putting it into the form $y' + p(t)y = g(t)y^{\alpha}$, but was unable to. Ideas?

Comment: $x'=x\cos y+\sin 2y$

Comment: Are you sure this has a solution in terms of elementary functions? Wolfram alpha does not think so.

Comment: @Shahab I've tried W|A, but didn't get anything as well. Artem, We are allowed to just flip it like that?

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the question properly. It was looking for $x$, not $y$.

Comment: Your equation has mismatched parentheses. Is the right side supposed to be $$\frac1{x(\cos(y)+\sin(2y))}$$ or $$\frac1{x\cos(y)+\sin(2y)}$$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x\cos(y) +\sin(2y)}=\frac{1}{x\cos(y) +2\sin(y)\cos y}\\
\frac{d(\sin y)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x+2\sin y}$$
Then $$\frac{dx}{d(\sin y)} -x=2\sin y\\xe^{\int -d(\sin y)}=\int 2\sin ye^{\int -d(\sin y)}d(\sin y)\\xe^{-\sin y}=2\int \sin ye^{-\sin y}d(\sin y)=-2e^{-\sin y}(\sin y+1)+c\\x+2\sin y+2=ce^{\sin y}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you look at $x$ as a function of $y$, just as Artem suggested, the differential equation becomes simple.

The general solution is $$x =c_1 e^{\sin (y)}-2 \sin (y)-2$$ which is difficult to inverse in the most general case (the problem is only simple if $c_1=0$).

However, playing a little, there is an explicit form using Lambert function and the result is
$$-\sin ^{-1}\left(W\left(-\frac{1}{2} c_1
   e^{-\frac{X}{2}-1}\right)+\frac{X}{2}+1\right)$$ which is not the nicest result I ever saw.